# How to install Ubuntu in UEFI or load in Legacy while Windows is in UEFI?

Tags: system-installation, uefi, windows-8, grub-legacy

I've been trying to install Ubuntu on my Windows 8 laptop. I've partitioned the drive created an Ubuntu DVD and disabled secure boot options.

When I tried to load the DVD, the only option I got was to load it in Legacy Boot mode; there was no UEFI option. So I installed it in the Legacy Boot mode, and now I can't access Ubuntu. Windows seems to have been unaffected, but I can't use Ubuntu. Ubuntu was installed, I just can't load it in either Legacy or UEFI mode.

I think this is because I installed it in Legacy mode while Windows was in UEFI, but I don't know how to get around that and install it in UEFI.

Can someone help me resolve this without doing irreversible damage to my laptop?

Comment: Have you see this question? http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In a dual boot system, how does the BIOS choose which bootloader to run?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/981382/in-a-dual-boot-system-how-does-the-bios-choose-which-bootloader-to-run)

Answer (score -1):

Use EasyBCD software(Non-commercial freeware) in Windows to add Ubuntu to the boot menu when booting. Go here for detailed info of using it-
[How to use EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/)

Download it here-
[EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/Download/Register/1)

Comment: The last I heard, EasyBCD was useless for managing a Windows/Linux dual-boot configuration in EFI mode.