# boot-repair it not detecting windows and hence no grub menu item for booting windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, kubuntu

I have problems getting kubuntu installed and dual boot together with windows 10. I have two disks one for windows and one kubuntu. I would like to have grub installed on the kubuntu disk and have it dual the windows.

Boot-repair gives this output:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/CcFgmQ3xY8/

I have tried the os-prober, grub update and boot-repair but none of them gives a installation that produces a grub menu item to boot windows. If I change my bios to boot the windows disk it works fine. Booting the ubuntu goes fine from the disk with grub/kubuntu.

It looks like I need the boot-repair to find my windows installation before I can get this to work. But how?

Comment: You have Windows installed in Legacy mode and Ubuntu in UEFI mode. Different modes aren't compatible for dual-boot with Grub. It's preferable to have both in UEFI mode but if you don't want to reinstall Windows, then you'll have to reinstall Ubuntu in Legacy mode.

Comment: Another problem can occur, when the NTFS file system is left in a special state, when Windows was hibernated or semi-hibernated alias 'fast startup'. You can solve this problem by *starting Windows and rebooting it* (not 'shutdown'). You can also change the setting of Windows, so that it shuts down completely instead of hibernating or semi-hibernating (turn off fast startup).

Comment: Since two drives you can dual boot but only from UEFI boot menu, not grub. UEFI and BIOS/CSM/Legacy are not compatible. Once you start booting in one mode you cannot switch. Best to have both systems in same boot mode and both UEFI since newer hardware. Microsoft has required vendors to install Windows in UEFI boot mode since 2012. To turn off fast start up: http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In a dual boot system, how does the BIOS choose which bootloader to run?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/981382/in-a-dual-boot-system-how-does-the-bios-choose-which-bootloader-to-run)

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I wonder what made you conclude that windows is installed legacy mode? I have confirmed that it is the case since it cannot boot in EFI mode if that is selected from the BIOS. I too wonder is running boot-repair/rebair MBR could have installed a Legacy bootloader? And that being the reason for it is in Legacy mode. I not capable to reinstall Windows but would love to repair/install UEFI bootloader for windows.

Comment: @sudodus I did make sure that I rebooted properly.

Comment: @oldfred This means that I need to have my windows running EFI boot. Is that possible with Linux tools?

Comment: You do not have to convert. And difficult to convert Windows. Windows only boots from MBR with UEFI and only from gpt with UEFI, so you also have to convert drive. While maybe possible for an advanced Windows user, generally just easier to backup your data and re-install Windows. How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS, for both Windows & Ubuntu is then how it installs.

Answer (score 0):

EFI partitions are your friend, one per drive:

- FAT32 format
- About 200-400MB
- "boot" flag

Windows usually handles this itself.

With *ubuntu, create/verify it manually on your disk in GParted in the Ubuntu Live USB/CD before entering the Ubuntu installer.

Not sure if that helps this specifically, but that's how I would have tried to avoid/solve this. It may help others with a similar problem.

Comment: It sounds like a good idear to run purely EFI, but I cannot figure out how I convert my windows installation to do that. Do I need to convert my /dev/sda1 to be a EFI partition? And which tool can install the proper EFI loader for windows? It looks like its boot-repair that have installed files to the drive, due to I ran it to "restore MBR". Currently it contain:

Comment: That part of this dilemma looks like a Windows question. SO, I won't add it to my answer, but it relates to "Ubuntu along side Windows", so I'll tell what I do... WITH Ubuntu, I 1. unplug the Ubuntu drive if I can (so Windows doesn't know its there) 2. If you need settings & such, backup your stuff (like /home/USER) in `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData` and 3. try some "repair" Windows or "Windows Troubleshooter" boot tool or something or just re-partition and re-install. Windows usually handles EFI/boot itself, so gotta' check that stuff. If you have trouble, search: "Make Repair Windows EFI"