# Windows7 Ubuntu dual boot issue partition table

Tags: dual-boot, mbr, boot-partition

I installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS after Windows 7. I had freed up some space from 2 different Windows volumes and shrank both to have around 104 gb of allocated disk space. Then I instated Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 . I probably should have chosen another method for manually formatting partitions. Now my Windows 7 doesn't boot up it complains about MBR.

The output of `free -h` is:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            19G        2.3G         15G        351M        1.7G         16G
Swap:          2.0G          0B        2.0G
```

`fdisk -l` shows partitions are out of order.

Is there any way I can fix the partition order and be able to boot up Windows 7?

```
Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    204861    202814    99M EFI System
/dev/sda2     206848 239946359 239739512 114.3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3  379048568 856529526 477480959 227.7G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  239947776 239949823      2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda5  239949824 379047935 139098112  66.3G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, perhaps this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/981382/in-a-dual-boot-system-how-does-the-bios-choose-which-bootloader-to-run and Windows 7 is not safe anymore. If you have no problem to upgrade to Windows 10, let's do it.

Comment: You are showing both ESP & bios_grub. ESP is for Windows & Ubuntu UEFI boot and bios_grub is for Ubuntu to boot from gpt drive in old BIOS mode. You should not mix boot modes, or only use UEFI.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Thanks @Sadaharu, but I am unable to upgrade to windows10 as my hardware/motherboard architecture doesn't support that.  Thanks@oldfred.

Comment: yes I see  2 bios boot options after pressing F2/F12 one for windows boot manager and other for ubuntu. I was able to loginto windows7 with  Windows boot manager.

Comment: On another note, the second unallocated volume/partition still show up as "Unallocated" under windows 7, so Ubuntu is unable to see the second unallocated partition and by default install itself on the first unallocated/available partition when  " Install ubuntu alongside them (windows7)"  is selected during boot also it allocate just 2 GB to swap by default. So I would think that manually selecting partition size is always wiser, as then it would show all available partition and you can choose a higher swap size.

Comment: @bhismapitamaha I believe you are trying to install WIndows 10 64bit. Try installing a 32 bit version.