# Unable to load Windows 8 after installing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, boot-repair

Help me to get back my Windows 8. Below is my Boot-Info report.
boot-repair-4ppa125                                              [20201028_1739]

```
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Windows 7/8/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Syslinux MBR (5.00 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /syslinux.cfg /bootmgr /boot/bcd /ldlinux.sys 
                       /KERNEL.SYS /COMMAND.COM

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda5 starts 
                       at sector 63.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
    Boot files:        /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

sda8: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.04
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 32776 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg 
                       /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi /ldlinux.sys


================================ 3 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   FreeDOS (boot) on sda1
OS#2:   Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on sda6
OS#3:   Windows 7 on sda2

============================ Architecture/Host Info ============================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, focal, x86_64)


===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS is EFI-compatible, and is setup in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled.

efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,3000,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(4,MBR,0x397a8933,0x1ab0bffe,0x59bfa802)/HD(3,MBR,0x0,0x6fac9000,0x8e800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)RC
Boot0001* USB Hard Drive (UEFI) - SanDisk Cruzer Blade  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/USB(0,0)/USB(0,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x62150ec3,0x800,0xee8400)RC
Boot0002* Notebook Hard Drive   BBS(HD,,0x500)................-.U.......U.A.U....................................c........A.........................
Boot0003* USB Hard Drive - SanDisk Cruzer Blade BBS(7,,0x500)...................................................................v........A...........................
Boot2001* USB Drive (UEFI)  RC
Boot2002* Internal CD/DVD ROM Drive (UEFI)  RC
Boot3000* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk    RC
Boot3001* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk    RC
Boot3003* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk    RC

bed45d1c9554cea09924d3814cb7c446   sda7/BOOT/fbx64.efi
4487628005555bfd4a4c0a47211e0700   sda7/BOOT/mmx64.efi
98bea152fadd26c4e9136916f6cc32a8   sda7/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
4487628005555bfd4a4c0a47211e0700   sda7/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
f7a57b08bc7c1c85417ae4cea582d1d4   sda7/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
f7a57b08bc7c1c85417ae4cea582d1d4   sda7/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  liveusb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda2    : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda3    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda5    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda6    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios
sda7    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda8    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    is-winboot
sda2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    notwinboot
sda3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda5    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda6    : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda7    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda8    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda2    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda3    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda5    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda6    : not-sepboot,  with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
sda7    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda8    : maybesepboot, no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x397a8933
      Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
sda1         16351232   32704511   16353280   7.8G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
sda2         32704512  341288959  308584448 147.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda3        341288960  447787007  106498048  50.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda4        447791102 1953523711 1505732610   718G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
sda5        447791104 1814984703 1367193600   652G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda6       1814986752 1873577983   58591232    28G 83 Linux
sda7  *    1873580032 1874163711     583680   285M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
sda8       1874165760 1953523711   79357952  37.9G 83 Linux
Disk sdb: 7.47 GiB, 8004304896 bytes, 15633408 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x62150ec3
      Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sdb1  *     2048 15633407 15631360  7.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:1000GB:scsi:512:4096:msdos:ATA HGST HTS541010A9:;
1:8372MB:16.7GB:8373MB:fat32::lba;
2:16.7GB:175GB:158GB:ntfs::;
3:175GB:229GB:54.5GB:ntfs::;
4:229GB:1000GB:771GB:::lba;
5:229GB:929GB:700GB:ntfs::;
6:929GB:959GB:30.0GB:ext4::;
7:959GB:960GB:299MB:fat32::boot, esp;
8:960GB:1000GB:40.6GB:ext4::;
sdb:8004MB:scsi:512:512:msdos:SanDisk Cruzer Blade:;
1:1049kB:8004MB:8003MB:fat32::boot, lba;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                   
â”œâ”€sda1 vfat     9427-9781                            397a8933-01                                      
â”œâ”€sda2 ntfs     F440F49840F462B2                     397a8933-02                                      
â”œâ”€sda3 ntfs     01D5E957291CAF70                     397a8933-03                                      
â”œâ”€sda4                                               397a8933-04                                      
â”œâ”€sda5 ntfs     01D5E954CF6A1BE0                     397a8933-05                                      
â”œâ”€sda6 ext4     d789e46c-eb08-44b5-93e4-4498c3b54d4f 397a8933-06                                      
â”œâ”€sda7 vfat     8025-A7A1                            397a8933-07                                      
â””â”€sda8 ext4     28bf8362-80e9-499d-a809-84bea841e7ed 397a8933-08                                      
sdb                                                                                                   
â””â”€sdb1 vfat     CC3E-6B7D                            62150ec3-01                          UBUNTU 20_0 

df (filtered): _________________________________________________________________

       Avail Use% Mounted on
sda1     7.5G   4% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
sda2    40.9G  72% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
sda3    40.5G  20% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
sda5   420.7G  35% /mnt/boot-sav/sda5
sda6    19.6G  23% /mnt/boot-sav/sda6
sda7   276.7M   3% /mnt/boot-sav/sda7
sda8      35G   0% /mnt/boot-sav/sda8
sdb1     4.9G  34% /cdrom

Mount options: __________________________________________________________________

sda1   rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
sda2   rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda3   rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda5   rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda6   rw,relatime
sda7   rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
sda8   rw,relatime
sdb1   ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

========================= sda1/syslinux.cfg (filtered) =========================

menu hshift 11
menu vshift 3
menu width 55
menu rows 15
menu margin 4
menu title Boot Menu
include live.cfg
menu background splash.png
default vesamenu.c32
menu color border 0 #ffffffff #ee000000 std
menu color title 0 #ffffffff #ee000000 std
menu color sel 0 #ff000000 #99ffffff rev
#menu color sel 0 #ffffffff #85000000 std
#menu color unsel 0 #ffffffff #ee000000 std
menu color pwdheader 0 #ff000000 #99ffffff rev
menu color pwdborder 0 #ff000000 #99ffffff rev
menu color pwdentry 0 #ff000000 #99ffffff rev
#menu color hotkey 0 #ffffffff #ee000000 std
#menu color hotsel 0 #ffffffff #85000000 std
menu color hotsel 0 #ff000000 #99ffffff rev
prompt 0
timeout 100
noescape 1
nocomplete 1
allowoptions 0

================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1
            ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1
            ?? = ??             chain.c32                                      1
            ?? = ??             menu.c32                                       1
            ?? = ??             vesamenu.c32                                   1

=============== sda1: Version of COM32(R) files used by Syslinux ===============

 chain.c32                          :  COM32R module (v4.xx)
 menu.c32                           :  COM32R module (v4.xx)
 vesamenu.c32                       :  COM32R module (v4.xx)

========================== sda6/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=d789e46c-eb08-44b5-93e4-4498c3b54d4f /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda7 during installation
# /home was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=28bf8362-80e9-499d-a809-84bea841e7ed /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

======================= sda6/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

==================== sda6: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 868.463981628 = 932.506099712  boot/vmlinuz                                   1
 868.463981628 = 932.506099712  boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-26-generic                  1
 879.933959961 = 944.821895168  boot/initrd.img                                2
 879.933959961 = 944.821895168  boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-26-generic               2
 879.933959961 = 944.821895168  boot/initrd.img.old                            2

===================== sda6: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17123 Apr 15  2020 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 42128 Apr 15  2020 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12894 Apr 15  2020 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 Apr 15  2020 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1424 Apr 15  2020 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Apr 15  2020 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Apr 15  2020 41_custom

===================== sda7/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid d789e46c-eb08-44b5-93e4-4498c3b54d4f root hd0,msdos6 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings

========================= sdb1/syslinux.cfg (filtered) =========================

DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/

==================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1
            ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1


======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================

Unknown BootLoader on sda4

00000000  f7 da 09 97 9e b6 31 3e  c7 ba b7 fb 49 61 0f ca  |......1>....Ia..|
00000010  14 83 30 06 83 f4 e2 1b  73 b3 a6 e6 8c 1e 79 5b  |..0.....s.....y[|
00000020  b7 cd bc f4 8f bc f6 49  3f 48 f8 7c 72 4e fa d0  |.......I?H.|rN..|
00000030  5b bd 0b 70 a5 67 d7 b4  e3 b0 29 fd db 44 3a a1  |[..p.g....)..D:.|
00000040  12 a5 4b 07 0b 40 13 37  db c6 02 c7 09 ac 4f 4a  |..K..@.7......OJ|
00000050  94 14 a7 20 8d 10 48 7b  c3 c1 75 10 19 d2 52 33  |... ..H{..u...R3|
00000060  d8 80 f1 80 1b f9 4e ae  7a 75 a4 84 83 a9 f7 4e  |......N.zu.....N|
00000070  7c 46 f6 d1 62 1a 07 88  99 90 a4 12 43 ed 37 3f  ||F..b.......C.7?|
00000080  2c 96 18 95 a1 0b cd c9  ba 93 eb d6 91 c1 6e ca  |,.............n.|
00000090  f8 1e 43 89 66 51 0c 74  77 d8 20 4a b3 6d 92 b5  |..C.fQ.tw. J.m..|
000000a0  77 37 e1 a5 df 59 8d 3e  38 a3 63 ba 01 c1 d0 5c  |w7...Y.>8.c....\|
000000b0  36 d0 e2 2a db 41 e4 81  58 ad 3f 79 54 85 72 c0  |6..*.A..X.?yT.r.|
000000c0  65 1b 99 23 2d 82 5e d0  83 3e 89 d9 92 8f 42 ba  |e..#-.^..>....B.|
000000d0  90 fe e3 4b 69 19 3f da  3e 08 fd 76 8a 65 da 10  |...Ki.?.>..v.e..|
000000e0  f7 48 58 5e df fa 37 c2  9c 00 0f af 50 ee e1 30  |.HX^..7.....P..0|
000000f0  5d a9 1e 6e 8b 21 ec c3  03 50 71 f3 d7 35 08 73  |]..n.!...Pq..5.s|
00000100  29 d5 0c 3f 70 e5 f4 d3  a1 b8 5d d8 6f 4d ab e7  |)..?p.....].oM..|
00000110  6c f3 e4 31 f4 df 2f 07  fd 5f 02 a9 d5 01 71 19  |l..1../.._....q.|
00000120  a4 66 8a 3f da 71 d4 c8  88 b3 8f 8f 91 da 91 91  |.f.?.q..........|
00000130  59 4a b1 0a f4 70 ab e3  ed 82 d0 4f 8b d6 d6 44  |YJ...p.....O...D|
00000140  8a dd 0a 96 2e 47 f7 3b  17 78 1e 37 95 b0 d0 cc  |.....G.;.x.7....|
00000150  56 54 e4 37 96 a4 66 8b  09 ae c0 65 a5 2d be 47  |VT.7..f....e.-.G|
00000160  ef 5e 2d da e5 c2 f5 97  c2 7c e6 88 42 cb 51 26  |.^-......|..B.Q&|
00000170  f1 1d e0 30 9e 9f f5 a2  8a a3 bc b3 9f 3c ed f3  |...0.........<..|
00000180  b4 fc 96 31 31 99 19 2a  f5 fd e6 7f 58 e4 3e de  |...11..*....X.>.|
00000190  89 a7 44 a2 2c 02 7d 8a  36 2f 77 ec e6 d5 4a 4a  |..D.,.}.6/w...JJ|
000001a0  f7 ba 75 b7 8e 82 5f 5b  28 06 48 dc 16 24 27 54  |..u..._[(.H..$'T|
000001b0  71 dc d2 22 79 a8 e6 da  e1 a7 f2 22 64 c0 00 fe  |q.."y......"d...|
000001c0  ff ff 07 fe ff ff 02 00  00 00 00 b8 7d 51 00 fe  |............}Q..|
000001d0  ff ff 05 fe ff ff 02 b8  7d 51 00 10 7e 03 00 00  |........}Q..~...|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200


Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would purge (in order to remove grub-efi) and reinstall the grub2 of
sda6 into the MBR of sda.
Grub-efi would not be selected by default because: legacy-win no-win-efi 
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s win-legacy-basic-fix     

Confirmation request before suggested repair: __________________________________

LegacyWindows detected. The boot of your PC is in EFI mode. You may want to retry after changing it to BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode.
Are you sure you want to continue anyway?

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please set your BIOS in Legacy mode in order to start your Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, then type command [sudo update-grub] in order to add the Windows entry to your GRUB menu.
```

Comment: Question is offtopic as it is about windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In a dual boot system, how does the BIOS choose which bootloader to run?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/981382/in-a-dual-boot-system-how-does-the-bios-choose-which-bootloader-to-run)