# Unable to start Windows after Ubuntu installation

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I have Windows 10 installed for a while, and for programming reasons I decided to install Ubuntu (Dual Boot) in the same SSD and Ubuntu works fine, but the problem is that I can't boot into windows anymore, I didn't overwrite the Windows partition because I can still see the files...

When I start the computer there is a message

> System BootOrder not found. Initializating defaults.

and then Ubuntu starts (I don't know if this is related or just another error).

Here is an image of the partitions:

[image: here is an image of the partitions]

What I already tried is:

- Updating Grub

> ```
> sudo update-grub
> sudo update-grub2
> ```

- Installing boot-repair, then I click on Recommended repair and this shows up (also i have tried other things with it, and i keep getting the same thing):

[image: and this shows up]

- Tried to boot a windows installation from USB and i got this:

> System BootOrder not found. Initializating defaults.

None of those worked.

This is a 32-bit 4 GB RAM machine.

Comment: Your msdos partitioned disk implies a legacy install of Windows. Probably the Ubuntu install was done in UEFI mode.  How you boot the install media depends on how the install is done, and your machine BIOS/UEFI settings determine how the install media boots.  Check that legacy is prefered over UEFI or that compatibility mode is enabled (varies by machine).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In a dual boot system, how does the BIOS choose which bootloader to run?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/981382/in-a-dual-boot-system-how-does-the-bios-choose-which-bootloader-to-run)

Comment: i don't think that's the issue here... i have tried and tested every possible combination on my BIOS/UEFI settings and it still doesn't seem to work at all

Comment: Boot-Repair showed you a dialog telling you to do something in BIOS which your BIOS can't do, and as a result now you're stuck with an ugly gray Boot-Repair dialog box and you can't do anything. That's why you asked this question. Fortunately there is a solution for this.

Comment: @karel any info you might need to fix this i can give you.

Comment: after searching for answers i think the message i get "System BootOrder..." is related to this issue, i really need to fix this, i don't mind uninstalling Ubuntu to get windows os back again, but keep in mind that i can't use win installation from a USB i have tried and i get the same thing that i get when trying to load windows...

Comment: quick update after checking somethings i realized that i installed a 64 bit ubuntu, which doesn't really make any sense since i thought that i had a 32 bit machine, aparently i don't, i probably just installed a 32 bit windows os by mistake...