# How to isolate dual boot on 2 hard drives, such that there is no common bootloader (No Select OS Screen)?

Tags: dual-boot, bios

This is not a duplicate question. I don't want the select operating system screen.

Rather how can one install Windows and Ubuntu such that the only way to switch b/w OS is to go to BIOS and choose the boot disk.

In this manner both the operating systems are completely isolated & no update can break other installation, since there is no reference to another os.

Comment: You haven't said if BIOS/legacy or uEFI is involved... but if it's the former, have the MBR of each OS on it's own drive, meaning the machine BIOS will control which one boots (as only one drive MBR is used; and BIOS/firmware settings dictate which drive that is).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In a dual boot system, how does the BIOS choose which bootloader to run?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/981382/in-a-dual-boot-system-how-does-the-bios-choose-which-bootloader-to-run)

Comment: I suggest that you install each of the systems, when the other system is absent, and I think the best and most definitive way to do that is to disconnect the other drive. So, if one system is in an internal drive, unplug or disconnect it before connecting the drive where you want to install an operating system. [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312) shows details.

Comment: Be sure to install both systems in same boot mode, or both BIOS or both UEFI. And updates of boot loaders will probably change boot order in settings. As long as manually booting that will not be a major issue, but default boot may then change.

Comment: @guiverc It's UEFI. Thanks for the link, I will look into the implementation or few docs of UEFI to understand how it works.

Comment: @sudodus Yes, that will work if it's BIOS/Legacy. Not sure if it will in UEFI though.

Comment: @oldfred I had actually achieved this in an other computer by installing Windows under UEFI and Linux under BIOS (legacy) & then changing the boot priority in BIOS to select where to boot.

Comment: @Siddhant, It is particularly difficult in UEFI mode to keep the drives independent of each other, so it is a good idea to disconnect one drive (the internal one) when installing into the other drive (the external one). (And vice versa: keep the external drive disconnected when installing  into the internal one (but it is easy).) - I have done this many times, so I know that it works.